# Two aggregation functions group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to print the department names that have the sum of all salaries bigger than the average sum on departments.

[image]

```
SELECT d.department_name, SUM(e.salary)
FROM departments d, employees e
WHERE d.department_id = e.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_name
HAVING SUM(e.salary) > (SELECT AVG(SUM(salary)) from employees);
```

In the second select, after what do I have to group by `AVG(SUM(salary))`?

Comment: Look at using window sets (Over partition by) this allows you to get the average inline with the select. Example: http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions.php or perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847814/group-by-vs-partition-by-in-oracle

Answer (score 1):

You need to repeat the first query in the condition. This can be done with the WITH clause.

```
WITH dept_sums AS (SELECT d.department_name, SUM(e.salary) sum_salary
FROM departments d, employees e
WHERE d.department_id = e.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_name)

SELECT * FROM dept_sums d_s_1 WHERE d_s_1.sum_salary > (SELECT AVG(sum_salary) FROM dept_sums d_s_2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where window (analytic) functions come in handy. Below I am using `AVG()` as an analytic function to calculate the average total salary across all departments.

```
SELECT department_name, dept_salary FROM (
    SELECT d.department_name, SUM(e.salary) AS dept_salary
         , AVG(SUM(e.salary)) OVER ( ) AS avg_dept_salary
      FROM departments d INNER JOIN employees e
        ON d.department_id = e.department_id
     GROUP BY d.department_name
) WHERE dept_salary > avg_dept_salary;
```